# Doctrine 2.0 OneToMany Reference mapped by id or id being null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having an Entity which is in an oneToMany Reference to another entity. Having these Annotations:

```
/**
 * @var UserRoleDiscount[]|ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRoleDiscount", mappedBy="role", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
 private $discounts

/**
 * @var Role
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
 */
private $role;
```

So if role on `UserRoleDiscount` equals the `role_id` its working which is correct. For another case I want that if the role of the `UserRoleDiscount` is null it should also match.

Is there a way to do this with Annotations?

Comment: Add `nullable=true` perhaps? I'm not sure what your asking...

Comment: It's pretty complex to imagine your entities. Could you post annotations together with property name? and also please post opposite site of relation.

Comment: To help understanding my question here is a little example:
- The UserRole has the ID 201
- We have 3 UserRoleDiscounts one has Role ID 100, another has Role ID 201 and the last one has Role ID NULL

So what I want is that my UserRole has the UserRoleDiscounts with Role ID 201 and Role ID NULL